# OCaml - Compiling multiple files into one executable

Tags: compilation, ocaml

I've wrote a sudoku solver in OCaml and I want to create a single executable for it.

I've got 3 files: board.ml, solver.ml and main.ml

board.ml contains the type of the board, functions to read from files, check validity, ...

solver.ml contains the functions to solve a given sudoku. solver.ml uses functions from board.ml

main.ml is a program which uses functions from both board.ml and solver.ml to solve a sudoku provided by command line arguments.

I don't use .mli files because the signatures are defined in the .ml files like:

```
module Board :
    sig
        (* signature *)
    end
=
    struct
        (* implementations *)
    end
```

I've already been able to do this with all the code in board.ml like:

```
ocamlc board.mli board.ml main.ml -o sudoku_solver
```

The end result should be one executable called "sudoku_solver" so I can do:

```
./sudoku_solver "sudoku.txt"
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: I can't seem to compile these 3 files into a single executable using `ocamlopt` of `ocamlc`. ivg told me to use `ocamlbuild main.native` and this works but it requires me to change `Board.t` to `Board.Board.t` in Solver and main so that my code doesn't work in the toplevel anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use:

```
ocamlbuild main.native
```

and run it with

```
./main.native "sudoku.txt"
```

Comment: If I try that, I get an error: "File "solver.mli", line 3, characters 14-21: Error: Unbound type constructor Board.t". My .mli only makes the solve function available which looks like: val solve : Board.t -> Board.t

Comment: That is not a problem with compilation. OCaml puts your definitions into implicit module that has the same name as your file. That means, that the correct name for `Board.t` would be `Board.Board.t`

Comment: Thanks! I've changed my code and now it works! It's really confusing though, since this means that my code doesn't work in the toplevel anymore.

Comment: It depends on how you present it to your toplevel, replacing #use by #mod_use may solve your problem if it's what your using.

Comment: `#use` and `#mod_use` give the same error: "Error: Reference to undefined global 'Board'" So I have to replace `Board.Board.t` with `Board.t` again to get it working in the toplevel.